# Astoundingly large difference when evaulating trigonometric identity with NumPy

Tags: python, numerics

According to Wolfram Alpha and the [Sage computer algebra system](http://www.sagemath.org/), the following identity holds:
$$
\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{l_1-l_2}{d}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{(l_1-l_2)^2}{d^2}}}
$$

However, when I tried to verify it with an arbitrary example in NumPy, I noticed a rather large difference in the actual values computed by both sides of the idenitity. I have used the following code:

```
    l1 = 10; l2 = 8; d = 17
    from numpy import arctan2, cos, sin, sqrt

    alpha = arctan2((l1-l2),d)
    left = cos(alpha)

    right = sqrt(1 + ((l1-l2)**2)/(d**2))
```

Evaluating the results for `left` and `right` yielded the following:

```
    left = 0.99315060432287616
    right = 1.0
```

It is tempting to write this off as simply being a numerical error, but since I have very little experience in how large numerical errors can get, I am not so sure. Is this possible or am I missing something (obvious)?

Comment: your `right` is incorrectly entered.  it should be `right = 1/sqrt()`  When I enter the formulas into my Ti-89 I get a match out to 12 digits at 0.99315...

Comment: Yeah, I think he would have caught that if the square root expression had been evaluated correctly.

Comment: yeah, when I entered his expression I got 1.007, which definitely would have been visible.

Comment: Oh, really. That is embarrasing. Thank you for noticing.

Comment: Made this mistake before myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a suspicion that your Python expression for the right-hand side is doing integer division, not floating-point division. As a result, `((l1-l2)**2)/(d**2)` is being evaluated as zero, and the term inside the square root is one.

In fact, you forgot the reciprocal in your right-hand expression as well, but that's not the first problem...

In MATLAB:

```
>> l1 = 10; l2 = 8; d = 17;
>> alpha = atan2((l1-l2),d)
alpha =
    0.1171
>> left = cos(alpha)
left =
    0.9932
>> right = 1/sqrt(1 + ((l1-l2)^2)/(d^2))
right =
    0.9932
```

Comment: I've gotten into the habit of using `from __future__ import division` at the top of all my python scripts for this purpose.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving, turn that into an answer and I'll bet you get some serious rep for that. Good advice.

Answer (score 7):

As Michael C. Grant pointed out, the problem is that the division operation is integer division, not floating point division.  In versions of Python before 3, dividing two integers using `/` rounds down to an integer.  This behavior can be changed by adding

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of your script.  Note that this declaration changes the behavior of `/` only for the current file.  If you want the original behavior occasionally, use `//` (double slash).  This is discussed in more detail here:

[PEP 238 -- Changing the Division Operator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238)

Note that while most languages including C have similar semantics for division, the semantics are more confusing in Python because integers are not usually promoted to floats when passed to functions.  Thus, a function written as if it was operating on floats may in fact be operating on integers.